# How to merge column with index in Python, like data pivot (see example)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, indexing

I am dealing with the big data csv file but need some help.

Let's say we have a simple dataframe like coordinate：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbYFC.png)

Now for every index and column we have only one value. i wanna change it to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDnpl.png)

Is it possible to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas Melt function does this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
df.melt()

  variable  value
0        A      0
1        A      2
2        A      8
3        A      2
4        B      1
5        B      5
6        B      5
7        B      3
```